# How can I simplify a radical in the numerator?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the following problem to simplify and I am lost on how to proceed:

$\frac{\sqrt{1-x}+3}{2}$

I'm aware that I can rewrite $\sqrt{1-x}$ as $(1-x)^\frac{1}{2}$ but then I don't know where to go from there.

The solution provided is $\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}+2}$.

How can I arrive at this solution? More granular baby steps very much appreciated.

Comment: It's not true in general.  Take $x=1$ for example

Comment: and even worse as $x \to 0+$

Comment: To me, nothing could be simpler than the original expression.

Comment: I tried to answer the wrong question in my book. My bad. The solution is the incorrect one - sorry. But, out of curiosity, how would one simplify a radical in the numerator?

Comment: @DougFir:  When you say "radical in the denominator" (though your title says numerator) do you mean like $\dfrac 1{\sqrt2}$ or $\dfrac 1{\sqrt2 -1}$ or something else?

Comment: If the denominator is of the form $\sqrt{a} \pm b$, then you can multiply the numerator and denominator by $\sqrt{a} \mp b$

Comment: I meant numerator not denominator sorry. I think David answered it? I would factor using the property `a^2-b^2 = (a-b)(a+b)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These two expressions are not equal.

\begin{array}{c|cc}
x  &  \frac{\sqrt{1-x}+3}{2}  &  \sqrt{\frac{1}{x} + 2}  \\ \hline
2  &  \text{undefined}  &  \sqrt{\frac{5}{2}}  \\
1  &  \frac{3}{2}  &  \sqrt{3}  \\
0  &  2  &  \text{undefined}
\end{array}

Answer (score 2):

You can write $$\frac{\sqrt{1-x}}{2}+\frac{3}{2}$$